# How to compare array values preserving keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I can't figure out how to check if array values are equal or not. Array always have only 2 keys, need to preserve them, keys unknown. E.g.:

```
$arr = array(
    5 => 180,
    3 => 120
);

if ($arr['key1_value'] != $arr['key2_value']) {
    $variable = $arr['key1'];
} else {
    $variable = ($arr['key1'] + $arr['key2']) / 2;
}
```

Comment: need to preserve them - what  a key in the  else ?

Comment: I need to preserve key indexes to use later. Following my example, if values aren't equal, my $variable = first_key_index, else $variable = (first_key_index + second_key_index) / 2.

Comment: What if values of those keys are arrays themselves?

Comment: There is no such possibility. keys and values are alwyas integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so clear...
But if I refer to your comments, I should say that this approach could solve your problem:

```
// Here is your data
$arr = array(
    5 => 180,
    3 => 120
);

// You seem to be interested by keys as a return, so flip the array
$flip = array_flip($arr);

// Return a mean or a key, depending on comparison between flip and original array
$variable = (count($flip) < 2) ? array_sum(array_keys($arr))/2 : array_shift($flip);
```

To clarify the last line:

- If the number of values in $flip is lower, that means your two values are equals (because two same keys can not be accepted after the flip): in this case, we return the mean of keys (here it works because you confirmed that keys are always intergers)
- If not, the first key is returned (I think it is what you expected, but not sure)

*EDIT: In my proposition, I did a *count* on the array. As you said it is always 2 compared values, I replaced it directly by "2".*

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that did a trick!

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_values()` and `array_keys()` to get array's of the values and keys, but with a zero based (predictable) set of keys

```
$arr = array(
    5 => 180,
    3 => 120
);
$v = array_values($arr);
$k = array_keys($arr);

if ($v[0] != $v[1]) {
    $variable = $k[0];
} else {
    $variable = ($k[0] + $k[1]) / 2;
}
```

Comment: $variable use key indexes, not values. That's why it became difficult for me.

Comment: Then swap to use `array_keys()`

Comment: But then the `if ($v[0] != $v[1]) {` makes no sense as you can NEVER have 2 KEYS the SAME i.e. EQUAL

Comment: Which numbers were you wanting to compare? the `5 and 3` or the `180 and 120` ?? I am not a little confused

Comment: if values aren't equal $variable must be 5 OR 3, else must be 4 ((5+3) / 2).

Comment: SO `if 180 != 120 then v=5 else v = ((5+3) / 2)` Is that what is wanted

Comment: That's absolutely correct

Comment: So thats a simple use of both those functions. Simples